# Elastic search exact match multiple fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I read from elastic search documentation here which recommends not to use exact value fields in multi match query.

[Elastic Search Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_value_fields.html)

I am kind of facing an issue where I have dynamic number of non alayzed fields for which I want to do an exact match across multiple fields. (As the number of fields change frequently, I don't want to use a term or match query)

I know we can do a wild card match on field name in multi match query, but that doesn't work for my case where my fields are not analyzed and I want to match exact query text.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

If needed, I will post my elastic search settings/mappings.

Comment: Documentation says dont mix analyzed and not_analyzed fields. If all your fields are not analyzed I guess it wont be a problem.

Comment: Some of them are analyzed with custom analyzer (edge n gram) and some of them not analyzed